# Why cin accepts string inputs after including String header

Tags: c++, string, iostream, cin

I am new to C++ programming. I was trying to take user inputs and put them in a variable and i was using `cin` .  It was working for integer's and other's except `strings`. So, when I searched around I found that I have to include `<string>` header. I just want to understand, what changes occurred by including string header? I thought that `cin` is overloaded by a function defined in the string header. So, I started looking into string header and I could not find `cin` overloaded or any function defined there at all. Can any one tell me how `cin` started accepting string inputs after including `<string>`?

Comment: Please note C++ is case-sensitive - it's `string`, not `String`.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, yes i know that. i might have just typed it wrong. Thanks. i am editing the question

Comment: [`std::cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) is not a function, it's an `std::istream` object. You won't find an overload for it, only functions can be overloaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`<string>` defines the functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt)

```
template <class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& 
    operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os, 
               const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& str);

template <class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator>
std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& 
    operator>>(std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& is, 
               std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& str);
```

These free, standard library functions, are what allows you to use a `std::string` with any stream that is or is derived from a `basic_ostream` or `basic_istream`.

Comment: I would say "standard library  functions" rather than "global functions".

Comment: @NeilButterworth I think the point of saying global function is to identify them as free functions.

Comment: @NathanOliver, so, there's actually no overloading then?

Comment: @InAFlash There's an overload for `operator>>`.

Comment: oh, got it. I was confused with cin. i was looking for overloading of cin, but, after reading your comment, i understood it. thanks

Comment: @InAFlash Yes and no.  The overload the `operator >>` for `std::string` to work with streams.  They aren't overloading `cin` itself.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  Well, a free function is not necessarily (or even normally) a global function. In most modern C++ code (and all Standard Library code) they will be inside a named namespace.

Comment: @NathanOliver, just one off the topic question, i was checking the code and saw that the file of string header was named just "string". while few other files were having .h extension. is there any reason for creating files without extensions?

Comment: @InAFlash The standard C++ headers don't have a `.h` .  The C headers and all others have a `.h`

Answer (score 1):

The `<string>` header mainly defines the standard library's [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class. Without it, you *have* no string class in C++: It's not integral to the language. Of course you could use `char*`-strings, C-style, but that's not how we typically do things in C++.

Along with `std::string`, that header also defines `>>` and `<<` operators for `std::string`'s and streams, so that you can do things like `std::cout << my_string` and `std::cin >> another_string`. That syntax is equivalent to `operator<<(std::cout, my_string)` and `operator>>(std::cin, another_string)`.

Important note: The C language's `<string.h>` header is completely different than C++'s `<string>`. The C language header is usable just like it is in C, and defines [certain functions working on `char*` (null-terminated) strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte). Don't confuse the two headers, nor the two kinds of "strings".